# Automatically insert newline after for loop in pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Suppose I have a block of code like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

I select them and press F2 to send them to the python console, then it looks like this:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(i)
```

and I need to change focus to the console and press return, otherwise the for loop will not run.

This is very annoying. Is there a way to make pydev automatically insert this return for me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, by design it works as you're seeing: it needs some unidented code to run, so, what you can do as a workaround is putting in your code an unindented 'pass' in the end and execute it too with F2 (the other choice is really going to the console to hit enter):

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i) 
pass
```